# Accesing index in list using loops in python

Tags: python

I am trying to figure out how to solve this question. I know the answer, but I cannot figure out  why it's correct.

```
primes = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11]
```

What does it contain after executing the following loop?

```
for i in range(2):
     primes[4 - i] = primes[i]
```

> answer: 2, 3, 5, 3, 2

I'm stuck in `primes[4 - i]...` part. Can somebody please explain this part? I know it is the index position.

Answer (score 2):

`range(n)` gives you a sequence of numbers from 0 to n - 1.

If you replace the `range` function by its sequence in your code you basically get this:

```
for i in [0, 1]:
     primes[4 - i] = primes[i]
```

Each time you loop, `i` will start from 0 and get bigger and bigger.
Which in turn means that `4 - i` will start from 4 and get smaller.

> 1st loop: 4 -i = 4 - 0 = 4
>
> 2nd loop: 4 - i = 4 - 1 = 3
>
> (and so on if your value in range was bigger than 2)

The line `primes[4 - i] = primes[i]` means that you're assigning to the index `4 - i` the value stored at the index `i`.

In your example, your loop is actually doing this:

> 1st loop: primes[4] = primes[0]
>
> 2nd loop: primes[3] = primes[1]

Giving you the result you currently have.

Answer (score 1):

This code starts by reversing the array, but it overwrites the end of the array so overall it just outputs a palindrome.

Answer (score 0):

The code is just swapping the last with first,second last with second and so on.
until the loop is over

Answer (score -1):

The array is build with indices:

```
0,1,2,...,n
```

You can enter each index by selecting its position e.g. `array[2]` gets you the third value of the array.

Your code, like @script8man explained, selects the 4-ith index. in a `range(2)` (0,1), it will return the 4th and 3rd index, this index is overwritten with the i-th index (0,1).